# Docx: can't seem to get a bulleted list to render

Tags: docx, wordprocessingml

I'm building a DocX document essentially from scratch with XML. I have a very simple goal: create a bullet-point list, like a `ul` in HTML. Reading the [WordProcessingML specification for numbered lists (section 2.9)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Office%20Open%20XML%201st%20edition%20Part%204%20%28PDF%29.zip), I created what I thought would satisfy this. Here's what my `numbering.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:numbering xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
  <w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="1">
    <w:multiLevelType w:val="singleLevel"/>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
      <w:start w:val="1"/>
      <w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/>
      <w:lvlText w:val="&#8226;"/>
      <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:pos="360" w:val="num"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:hanging="360" w:left="360"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
      </w:rPr>
    </w:lvl>
  </w:abstractNum>
  <w:num w:numId="1">
    <w:abstractNumId w:val="1"/>
  </w:num>
</w:numbering>
```

So I have an abstract numbering with id 1, defined with a single level with some indentation and a bullet as the lvlText (the symbol `&#8226;` renders as `•`). The abstract numbering of 1 is referenced by the "actual" numbering of 1.

And here's what my `document.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00851CFD" w:rsidRDefault="00851CFD">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>This is a test</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
          <w:numId w:val="1"/>
        </w:numPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>foo</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
          <w:numId w:val="1"/>
        </w:numPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>bar</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
          <w:numId w:val="1"/>
        </w:numPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>baz</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="008E365B" w:rsidSect="008E365B">
      <w:pgSz w:h="15840" w:w="12240"/>
      <w:pgMar w:bottom="1440" w:gutter="0" w:left="1800" w:right="1800" w:top="1440"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

There's an initial paragraph, and then three lines that specify a `numId` of `1` (pointing at the numbering we defined earlier), and an indentation level of 0. So what we should get is something like:

> This is a test
>
> - foo
> - bar
> - baz

But when I open this in microsoft word, it instead renders (roughly) as

> This is a test
>
> 1. foo
> 2. bar
> 3. baz

And when I open it in Google Docs, it simply renders the text:

> This is a test
>
> foo
>
> bar
>
> baz

It really seems like I'm following the specification laid out in the standard. I don't know what piece I'm missing. Why do the bullets not get rendered? What can I do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you are correctly referencing the numbering part from your document. Word uses the default (1, 2, 3, ...) numbering when it fails to find the numbering definition.

The `word/_rels/document.xml.rels` file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
  <Relationship Id="rId1"
                Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering" 
                Target="numbering.xml"/>
  <!-- other relationships go here. -->
</Relationships>
```

Comment: That was it. I figured it out by painstakingly duplicating files one by one from a working file :) Also, for some reason I had to add an `Override` element to `[Content_Types].xml` or else it would complain at me: `<Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml"/>`

Comment: The question, the answer, and the comment combined helped me get the solution.