# Office Open XML bullet list

Tags: xml, ms-word, openxml, docx, bulletedlist

I'm trying to create a office open xml document with a bullet list in it. But instead of showing the bullets, the document shows a numbered list.

This is what I look for:

- Paragraph 1
- Paragraph 2

And instead I get the following list:

1. Paragraph 1
2. Paragraph 2

I already deeply digged the Web and Googled a lot. I read the documentation from http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML.php and from the following resources:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee922775(office.14).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee922775(v=office.14).aspx

and on StackOverflow as well.

I also already tried to create a new Word document with a bullet list in it and then I copied the code from the file itself without success.
This is the content of my numbering.xml file:

```
<w:numbering [all namespaces follow]>
<w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="0">
    <w:multiLevelType w:val="multilevel"/>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
        <w:start w:val="1"/>
        <w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/>
        <w:lvlText w:val=""/>
        <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:tabs>
                <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="720"/>
            </w:tabs>
            <w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="720"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:lvl>
    ... Other levels omitted ...
</w:abstractNum>
<w:num w:numId="1">
    <w:abstractNumId w:val="0"/>
</w:num>
</w:numbering>
```

While this is what I have in my document.xml (only the relevant part)

```
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
            <w:numId w:val="1"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>
            Paragraph 1
        </w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Already tried with/without style information, different fonts, different symbols, ...

I'm using a XSLT sheet to create all the XML files, the folder structure and the final .docx file (the transformation is called from within a Java application)

Thank you

Comment: I found also this answer from [marek-dzikiewicz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/698347/marek-dzikiewicz) that I need to test. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905221/3801659

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

I did the "mistake" of doing a copy+paste from Internet of the following line:

```
<Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml"/>
```

But the original line had two invisible characters in the word `numbering` between the `b` and the `e`! Very hard to find. I found it thanks to my IDE which highlighted a ***typo***!

[image: The typo as shown in IntelliJ]

So be careful!